# Using React.js Axios to update data results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, jsx

I'm using ReactJS as a javascript library with JSX and I am getting the data using axios. The received data must be taken again every 5 seconds. What is the most efficient and good way to do this?

I was thinking of using setInterval(), but wasn't sure where to put the method.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get('API LINK')
        .then(res => {
          setResults(res.data.result)
        });
  },[]);

  const Results = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {results.map( (i)=>(<li key={i.sys_id}><h1>{i.u_dashboard}</h1> 
        Calls in Queue (CIQ): {i.u_calls_in_queue}
        {"\n"}Longest Active Call (LAC): {i.u_longest_active_call}</li>)) }
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use setInterval in useEffect, and to clear the interval it should be returned in useEffect as the return will be triggered once the component will unmount.

```
useEffect(()=>{
     ...

    const interval = setInterval(() => {

    axios.get('API LINK')
        .then(res => {
          setResults(res.data.result)
        });

    console.log('Every 5 seconds');
    }, 5000);

   return () => clearInterval(interval);

  },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the fetch request in a function to be called on an interval

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get('API LINK')
      .then(res => {
        setResults(res.data.result)
      });
  };

  fetchData(); // <-- invoke on mount too!
  const timerId = setInterval(fetchData, 5000);

  return () => clearInterval(timerId); // <-- return cleanup function
},[]);
```

This handles cancelling the interval callback when the component unmounts, but *doesn't* cancel any in-flight requests.

[axios cancellation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#cancellation)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  const source = CancelToken.source();

  const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(
      'API LINK',
      {
        cancelToken: source.token,
      },
    )
      .then(res => {
        setResults(res.data.result)
      });
  };

  fetchData();
  const timerId = setInterval(fetchData, 5000);

  return () => {
    source.cancel();
    clearInterval(timerId);
  };
},[]);
```